# SELECT newest entry by timestamp

Tags: sql, duplicates

If there exists rows with the same TimeStamp_2 I need the row with the newest TimeStamp_1

```
ID           TimeStamp_1        TimeStamp_2
------------------------------------------------
0000003259   2013-05-23 09:53   2013-05-23 09:55
0000003259   2013-05-23 09:52   2013-05-23 09:55
0000003257   2013-05-23 07:52   2013-05-23 07:53
```

How do I do that? (The above table is a JOIN if itself, hence several rows with same ID)

In the above example, the result set should contain this

```
ID           TimeStamp_1        TimeStamp_2
------------------------------------------------
0000003259   2013-05-23 09:53   2013-05-23 09:55
0000003257   2013-05-23 07:52   2013-05-23 07:53
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
     ID,
     TimeStamp_1,
     TimeStamp_2,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, TimeStamp_2 ORDER BY TimeStamp_1 DESC) AS RNum
    FROM TableName
)x
WHERE RNum=1
```

Answer (score 2):

From the data you have provided, the simplest way would seem to be an aggregation:

```
select id, min(TimeStamp_1) as TimeStamp_1, TimeStamp_2
from t
group by id, TimeStamp_2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found was I was looking for in techdo's reply, however.